# how can i deactivate dates in datepicker when it reaches its appointment limit per day?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
          <input class='datepicker' id="datepicker" name="dates" style="padding: 10px; margin: 1%;" onfocus="pickDate(this)"  readonly='true'>



                            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/date.css">
<script src="datejs/jquery-1.11.0.min1.js"></script>
<script src="datejs/jquery-ui.min1.js"></script>
```

```
$(function(){
  // Define an array to store your already selected Dates
  var selectedDates = [];

   var Dates = [];

  $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: 2, // to  appoint 2 days ahead of time


    dateFormat: 'MM-dd-yy',
// beforeShowDay: function(date) { // to disable saturday only
     function(date) { // to be open everyday.. monday to sunday

    var day = date.getDay();
    return [(day != 0), ''];



}
```

});

```
  // When your datepicker changes, add the value to the array (if it doesn't exist)
  $('.datepicker').change(function(){
      // Clear out the selectedDates and add each of the currently selected values
      selectedDates = [];

      // Add each of the currently selected Dates
      $('.datepicker').each(function(){
        if($(this).val().length > 0){
          // Add it to the collection
          selectedDates.push($(this).val());
        }

      });



  });

});
```

here's my code. so far..  what i can do is to disable the previous dates until current date. and 2 days ahead of time on the current date. i'm working on an appointment website. and i needed to disable dates on date picker when a certain limit is reached per day.. for example.  5 patients already picked oct 11 as their date of appointment. how can i disable the oct 11 date?

Comment: put a "working" example in jsfiddle.net or something and then I will help you :-)

Comment: <script src="datejs/jquery-1.11.0.min1.js"></script>
    <script src="datejs/jquery-ui.min1.js"></script>  i created an account on jsfiddle .net. i don't know how to add these resources?   do i have to put these on the  external resources input fields on the left or the whole file  of those resources? im new to js fiddle. :(

Comment: you don't need account :-) and you can add jquery (it is with UI) by clicking on gearwheel icon on top right of javascript code window.

Comment: :( i can't make it work.... i already put the script sources. and it turns out to be a blank text box.. the datepicker doesn't come out..  thank you for helping a newbie like me..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/awiwiwow/yz4x61xy/ did i put the jscript sources correctly?

Answer (score 0):

```
(your code + jQuery + jQueryUI);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yz4x61xy/2/

Here's working fiddle... and what's the problem ? :D

`pickDate()` - there is no such a function

Your code after fixes with disabled array of dates:

https://jsfiddle.net/yz4x61xy/4/

Ok, here's the final code showing how it should work... every time calendar appears, it sends an ajax request (waiting for response) and then reads the values from it applying disable or enabled to the date.

http://jsfiddle.net/yz4x61xy/5/

Comment: thank you for fixing it. i am working with an appointment website. what i wanted to do is when the specific date already  reached its limit  for example 5 people already picked that date as their appointment date.  that date will be disabled so  that others won't be able to pick it.

Comment: you need to ajax for that... from where you get your data about how many people are there already? you need to keep it somewhere... like in mysql database or something...

Comment: i am using mysql for my database..  i know how to get the number of people who picked that date.  but i don't know how can i transfer that value  to javascript.  what i wanted to do is  when i get the count of people who picked that date.. and reached the limit which is 5.  i will now transfer that value to the date picker and would trigger it  to disable that date.   is that even possible?

Comment: thank you for helping me... you're the best!  ill try to put it now on my project.. and try to combine it with my codes.. .